# Select Data from two tables where there is no common field between them at all

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I want to select data from two table but they have nothing in common.

> In table 'users' fields are uid, uname and uemail

and

> In table 'patients' fields are pid, pame, and pemail

Now i want to select all the users emails and patients email ids in one column.
How do i do that?

Comment: You need proper Search.. First search properly then Ask Question

Comment: I agree with Sandesh. Please, at least, try to Google your question.

Comment: Sorry. Sandesh & Robert. I googled, but didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html)

```
SELECT uemail FROM users
UNION 
SELECT pemail FROM patients;
```

If you want to distinguish from which table your email is, then add a column with a constant value:

```
SELECT 
    'users' as source, uemail 
FROM users
UNION 
SELECT 
    'patients', pemail 
FROM patients;
```

Please note that without the keyword `ALL` you'll only get distinct rows.

**Edit**

If you need the values of the other columns, just add them to your selects:

```
SELECT 
    'users' as source, 
     uid, 
     uname,
     uemail
FROM users
UNION 
SELECT 
    'patients', 
    pid,
    pname,
    pemail 
FROM patients;
```

Now you can filter with an WHERE clause. Please regard that the column names will be taken from the first SELECT statement.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT 
    'users' as source, 
     uid as id, 
     uname as name,
     uemail as email
FROM users
UNION 
SELECT 
    'patients', 
    pid,
    pname,
    pemail 
FROM patients
) u
WHERE
    u.id = 3;
```

Comment: This worked fine. but now if i want to search an email id in that returned rows, then.. WHERE clause?

Answer (score -1):

Just Simple
SELECT * FROM users,patients